# Find the value of $k$ that makes the following function continuous on minus $-\infty< x< \pi/2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
{3x^2+k \cos2x}{} & \text{if $x\le0$}, \\[6pt]
\dfrac{\tan x}{x}+ 3e^x &  \text{if $0<x<\pi/2$}. \\
\end{cases}$$

I'm considering both the sides to be $x=0$ to find $k=3.$ But is it the correct method, given the interval between $-\infty$ and $\pi/2$? Please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is at the zero, as long as $h(0)=\lim_{\rightarrow 0}h(x)$ is valid, then the function is continuous at $x=0$. In this case, we want $h(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}h(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}h(x)$.

Now $h(0)=k$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}h(x)=k$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}h(x)=1+3=4$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$h (0^-)=\lim_{x\to0^-}(3x^2+k\cos (2x) )$$
$$=0+k=k $$

$$h (0^+)=\lim_{x\to0^+}(\frac {\tan (x)}{x}+3e^x)=1+3=4$$

$h $ is continuous at $0$ if $k=4$.